# SQL WebReplication replisapi.dll?diag access denied

Tags: sql, iis, database-replication

I have a problem with web replication. I Have a SQL Server with a publication for merge and 1 WEB IIS Server where is installed `replisapi.dll`. both servers on same domain on same LAN

When I try to diagnose the `replisapi.dll` it give me access denied error.

https://MYWEBSERVER/SQLReplication/replisapi.dll?diag

after ask me the credential it give me this error

> **Access Denied because of no WebSyncDiagAccess.**

can you help me? thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two places you need to check.

Check application pool if it enables 32-bit applications. Enable it.
[image]

Then check application pool identity. Use administrator or local system. Other identity may not have enough permission to `replisapi.dll`.
[image]